# Does .NET Native compile all generics to native code?

Tags: .net, uwp, .net-native

MSDN: .NET Native is ahead-of-time (“AOT”) compilation: it turns your code into native machine code when you compile

I was wondering how it deals with generics?

Comment: Probably the same way it does with just-in-time (JIT) compilation. Is there any reason you are specifically asking about generics?

Comment: Someone more qualified might know for sure, but the usual ways of dealing with generics are (A) produce a separate version for each type set used (G<A> -> G_of_A, G<B> -> G_of_B), or (B) downcast generic to a general container type (so G<any type> would be really G<object>)

Comment: It just is not different.  The only possible complication is that .NETNative needs to know all of the type arguments that your code uses.  Which is simple to do, since it runs after all of your code is compiled it has access to all of the assemblies your program uses.  Also the reason it is only supported for appx packages, it has no trouble determining what assemblies you actually use since they are listed in the manifest. The only thing it cannot do reliably is detect code that you activate through Reflection, that's where you have to help with the rd.xml file.

Comment: As they describe, it is a AOT compilations (ahead-of-time). And some generics types can't be known to the run-time until you run the code. Usually generics are not friendly to AOT, and their type definition is maintained in memory at runtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a feature in that stack called Universal Shared Generics that help catch all the cases where our analysis hasn't properly identified a generic that you need at runtime. For these cases, you won't get optimal speed through that code path as there's a reasonably amount of redirection to get it to work. However, if you discover that a particular hot path is impacted, it's relatively simple to get the compiler to generate native code for those by having some stub code for us to find during analysis that has the desired type signatures.

It's been a part of the .NET Native runtime for some time. You can read about the it in [this announcement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/whats-new-for-the-net-native-compiler-and-runtime-in-visual-studio-2015-update-2/#what-s-new-in-the-net-native-compiler-and-runtime).